# Problems Summing up result of MySQL query

Tags: mysql

The following query returns what is displayed in the attached image.
What I thought would be very simple has turned out to be very complex. All I simply want to do is now total up the result into one row and column. In this case the sum would be 161. How do I do this? I've literally tried everything. I hope I've provided enough information.

[image]

```
SELECT
TRUNCATE
    (
        SUM(
            `assignment`.`percentage_achieved` *(
            SELECT
                `unitComponentWeighting`.`percentage_weighting` / 100
            FROM
                `unitComponentWeighting`
            WHERE
                `assignment`.`assignment_component_id` = `unitComponentWeighting`.`component_lookup_id`
            LIMIT 1
        )
        ),
        2
    ) AS `unit_percentage_grade`
FROM
    `assignment`
LEFT JOIN `assignmentType` ON `assignment`.`assignment_type_id` = `assignmentType`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `assignmentComponentLookup` ON `assignmentComponentLookup`.`id` = `assignment`.`assignment_component_id`
LEFT JOIN `unit` ON `unit`.`id` = `assignment`.`unit_id`
LEFT JOIN `assignmentSequence` ON `assignmentSequence`.`id` = `assignment`.`assignment_sequence_id`
LEFT JOIN `yearGroup` ON `yearGroup`.`id` = `unit`.`year_group_id`
WHERE
    `yearGroup`.`id` = 1
GROUP BY
    `assignment`.`unit_id`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing  this part
" GROUP BY
`assignment`.`unit_id` "

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that!